# How to get a copy of UITableViewCell with different reuseIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Given a prototype `UITableViewCell` (created in storyboard) with reuseIdentifier A, it is required -in code- to copy that cell to a new cell with a new reuseIdentifier B, in order to make some changes to cell subviews, it is required to keep any outlet connections unbroken.

**Use case:**
In app storyboard a `TableViewController` has a prototype cell that has some labels, these labels frames and formatting are needed to be changed in code at `viewDidLoad` so that these labels are aligned with some other views, I don't like to keep changing every cell after I dequeue it in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

I would like to change the cell once and use that changed cell as master copy.

**Update:**

I used `tag` property in `UITableViewCell` to mark the cells that I modified so that when I dequeue them next time I don't have to re-apply same changes again.

I don't have to change cell id now, thanks for thinking aloud together !

Comment: Why do you need copy? You can make another reference to the cell. What actually the condition is? can you please elaborate?

Comment: Have you registered an another reuseId or why do you need a copy with a new reuseId? The only way you should create reusable cells is dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier.

Comment: @ShehzadAli Solution came to me while considering your comment, Thank you very much !